# Viewing .bit Domain Names in Firefox

Tags: namecoin

I'm following the instructions on http://dot-bit.org/How_To_Browse_Bit_Domains and I have installed foxy proxy and I have gone to several .bit sites. But all of them I see are exactly the same. All of the .bit sites say the following?

Namecoin is a peer-to-peer, alternative distributed Domain Name System based on Bitcoin software. It provides cheap .bit domain names that are not regulated by any central authority.

Download the Namecoin client
Install the Namecoin client on your computer to access the Namecoin network and register your .bit domains.

Configure your DNS
Change your DNS settings on your computer or on your whole network to enable access to .bit websites.

Spread the word
Namecoin is still growing. Use the Facebook and Twitter share buttons on this page to spread the word and help it grow even faster!

Have the site owners not put any websites up and I'm seeing the default installation pages? Or have I configured my browser wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you have something set up incorrectly. The contents of, for example, http://dot-bit.bit should match http://dot-bit.org.

Comment: The conentents don't match. I remember they did an upgrade to the blockchain to prevent from a malicous attack. I'm not sure if that means they way of viewing sites changed or not. If so could it be that I'm reading instructions for the old way

Comment: I got it working. I had was using the proxy 178.32.31.43 and the port 80 and I changed Port 80 to port 8888 and it works

Comment: please post this as an answer when you are allowed to answer your own question (there is a cool-down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I had was using the proxy 178.32.31.43 and the port 80 and I changed Port 80 to port 8888 and it works –